# Explain about present perfect tense

Tags: verbs

What is difference of these sentences?where can i used it?

"i have walked since in the morning"

"i have been walking since in the morning"

Comment: The sentences should read: **I have walked since this morning** and **I have been walking since this morning.** Can you please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

First one is present perfect.
Second one is present perfect progressive.

First one, present perfect tenses in general, implies that you have walked since morning and at the time of speaking, you already stopped walking.

The second one, present perfect progressive tenses in general, implies that you have been walking since morning and is STILL walking at the time of speaking.